# Json iteration over multidimensional array gives undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, multidimensional-array

I've looked a lot of examples but I couldn't find anything to solve my problem. I have json array with following format ;

```
{ "value" : [
    { "...some variables...",
      "comments" : [
        { "user_name"   : "arascanakin",
          "picture_url" : "...some url..."
        }
      ],
      "error" : false,
      "msg"   : "some message"
    }
```

P.S. There may be syntax errors, I've written the JSON array manually. It's right.

I have the following jQuery to iterate over arrays:

```
$.each($task_array, function (i, task) 
{
    // some stuff
    $.each(task.comments, function(i, $task_comment)
    {
        // some stuff
        // $task_comment is undefined here
    }); 
});
```

The problem is `task.comments` is undefined when I set each comment element to `$task_comment`.

Any ideas to solve this problem? It seems correct to me but I read that JavaScript doesn't allow multidimensional arrays.

Comment: If your JSON data is correct, then your problem is not related to JSON but to how to access JavaScript objects/arrays. You are right, JavaScript does not have multidimensional arrays, but you can of course have arrays of arrays. There is not much to say here, really. If `task.comments` is an array, then `$task_comment` will be the value of the array entry: http://jsfiddle.net/7yJkG/. It seems the data is not like you think it is, double check it.

Comment: have you tried classic javascript? somethink like `tsk = task.comments; for(var i = 0; i < tsk.length; i++) { //do something with tsk[i]; }`

Comment: I'm sending this json by json_encode($return) statement. I don't give json by manually.

Comment: `$task_comment.user_name`  and `$task_comment.content` gives the right values, but I still get this error; Cannot read property 'length' of undefined line_no : second each iteration @FelixKling

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo with a more complete example (more data, more code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fiddled with your code and it works alright for me, once I fixed your json...

http://jsfiddle.net/zyBmn/1/

I wanted to post the json here, but it's not formatting correctly... see the fiddle

edit: tidier fiddle with several comments: http://jsfiddle.net/zyBmn/3/